# Add existing ruby to RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I had ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5 installed on my machine.I had install RVM with ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.0.

So i want to add existing  ruby 1.8.7 to RVM.How can i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install ruby 1.8.7 through RVM

```
rvm install ruby-1.8.7
```

To use existing system ruby

```
rvm use system
```

Answer (score 5):

1. `rvm install 1.8.7`     will install ruby 1.8.7
2. browse to your project folder in shell
3. `rvm use 1.8.7`        you are using 1.8.7 for this project
4. `rvm gemset create gemsetname`    create gemset for your project with 1.8.7
5. `gem install bundler`             install bundler you NEED to configure bundler for rails 2.3
6. `bundle install`       #install gems
7. add `rvm use 1.8.7-p352@gemsetname --create` in your .rvmrc file
8. enjoy :)

these steps will works fine in 3.x for 2.3 you need to configure bundle

Comment: Thank you, but i have ruby installed on my system i want to add that installed ruby to rvm.That can be use as "rvm use 1.8.7".

Answer (score 4):

The `rvm mount` command allows you associate existing ruby installs with rvm. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12169498/473691) for examples on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

when using rvm the best practice is to create a gemset

```
rvm gemset create mygemset
```

and then create a .rvmrc file

```
rvm --create --rvmrc ruby-1.8.7-p352@mygemset
```

Execute above command from the rails directory with obviously correct ruby version(install if not already present..rvm install ruby-1.8.7) and gemset.
This way rvm automatically set the correct ruby version for your project.

Hope this helps