# How do I associate a new rvm install with existing ruby versions?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I was having a problem with RVM, so I uninstalled and re-installed it.

The truth is I actually tried rbenv, but that didn't work out for me so I am trying to get rvm up and running again - without having to install duplicate versions of Ruby.

I have at least 1 existing version of Ruby installed:

```
ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

But when I do `rvm list` I get a blank list:

```
bash-3.2$ rvm list

rvm rubies


# Default ruby not set. Try 'rvm alias create default <ruby>'.

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

So my question has two parts:

- How do I see all the versions of Ruby on my system (given that rvm is not showing me any)?
- How do I associate the new RVM install with the existing versions of Ruby?

Or am I better off removing all existing versions of Ruby and re-installing everything? That seems like a pain in the ass though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an existing ruby to rvm using:

```
rvm mount /path/to/ruby
```

or:

```
rvm automount
```

but be careful as ruby installed in system might have hardcoded paths for gems - so gemsets would not work with it.

There is also new way of adding binary rubies (already compiled), for list of available builds for your platform run:

```
rvm list remote
```

and you can install those rubies using:

```
rvm mount -r 1.9.3
```

This might be default way of installing ruby to avoid compilation in next stable release of RVM - but it will work only for ruby 1.9.3+.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *want* to associate RVM with an existing Ruby, you just want to install a new Ruby.

You don't want to remove the system Ruby, either; OS X depends on it.

Install a new 1.8.7 under rvm, this way you can associate your *own* gemsets with it. Let OS X manage the default system Ruby, you just ignore it and use your own, managed solely by rvm.

(If you decide to go the rvm route.)